# Zend Date Weekday

Tags: php, zend-framework, datetime

In Zend Framework I want to find a number of week day.

`echo Zend_Date::WEEKDAY_DIGIT;`

But this returns **`e`**. Today is Wednesday. And I want to return 3 (or 2 if Monday is 0). How can I do it? I know how do it with `DateTime` class. But I need Zend_Date.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heyho,

small mistake there WEEKDAY_DIGIT is a constant that defines wich date placeholder is used for Weekday Digit (e). Try:

```
 $date = Zend_Date::now();
 print $date->get(Zend_Date::WEEKDAY_DIGIT);
```